# How to easily find out which games in pgn database were already analysed/processed

Tags: software, pgn

Which software (ideally free/open source (maybe Scid or Chessx) gives the possibility to easily see on the list of games (in PGN) which has: alternative moves or comments added?
Basically what I need is to have the possibility to see on the list of the games which were already analysed by me.
Any other suggestions on how to mark and visually distinguish already processed games would be appreciated.