extract pgn games containing comments into a separate file from a master database
pgn-extract is a fantastic tool and I use it a lot. However, I couldnt find an option to extract games containing comments (e.g. evaluations) into a separate file from a big master pgn database that does not contain any variants. Any help with this?

Related - https://chess.stackexchange.com/questions/43549/how-to-easily-find-out-which-games-in-pgn-database-were-already-analysed-process

If you would like to get in touch with me via email (I am the author of pgn-extract) I could probably add that feature.
